# SetBounds on background drawable in custom ImageButton

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-drawable, bounds, android-imagebutton

I'm trying to extend ImageButton and create my own with some graphics on top of image and backgrounds from standard ImageButton. I have to scale background size of an ImageView to have some space to draw other shapes on canvas. So in onDraw() method I call:

```
getBackground().setBounds(getWidth()/2-25, getHeight()/2-25, getWidth()/2+25, getHeight()
                /2+25);
```

To shrink background size and center it, and here's the weird thing: when I use it on genymotion (5.1.0 API 22) it works, however it doesn't work on my Huawei P-8 Lite (5.0.1 API 21), see the screenshots:
[image]

On the left you can see my custom ImageButton and on the right standard ImageButton, both have the same values in src and background xml attributes.

Does anybody know what's going on? Thanks for help in advance!

And here is the full source code:

```
    public class CustomImageButton extends ImageButton {

    private Paint bg;

    public CustomImageButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        bg = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        bg.setColor(Color.parseColor("#009688"));
        bg.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        getBackground().setBounds(getWidth() / 2 - 25, getHeight() / 2 - 25, getWidth() / 2 + 25, getHeight()
                / 2 + 25);
        canvas.drawRect(getWidth() / 2 - 25, getHeight() / 2 - 25, getWidth() / 2 + 25,
                getHeight() / 2 + 25, bg);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe replace each getWidth() call with canvas.getWidth() and each getHeight() with canvas.getHeight()?

Comment: same result, canvas.getWidth() and getWidth() are equal